# Globally disable all mouse input when a JDialog is showed

Tags: java, swing

I would like to implement what follows:
when my application perform some critics operations or produce some errors, i want to display an alert JDialog telling the user what is happening.

Now, because some errors may put my application into an inconsistent status, until they are resolved, i would like temporarily disable mouse event dispatch to all components (including JMenu, JToolbar, .. )except the showed JDialog.

Is there anyway to do that? Or I have to manually removed all mouse listeners from all of components of my application, and re-add them later?

Answer (score 6):

Make the dialog "modal" with [`setModal(true)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal%28boolean%29).

Comment: @Overbose: You can use `setModalityType()` (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType(java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType)) instead if you like but I couldn't find a @Deprecated warning anywhere. It's not good *style* because it blocks the whole UI and you should avoid that. But in your case, modal dialogs are the correct solution.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla : I think that blocking whole UI is exactly what i need because user will not procede with any other operation before having read the error displayed by the dialog and accepted the consequences. In anycase i will look to setModalityType() too.. thanks

Comment: @Overbose: This is exactly what `setModal()` does: It blocks all other windows as long as the dialog is visible. The lock goes away when you close the dialog. So when you need to block (which you shouldn't - it's bad taste), you should use `setModel(true)` instead of hacking your own solution.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: thanks for your suggestion. I read the doc and effectivily you are right. Anyway it seems not to work. I don't know why.

Comment: "seems not to work"? What doesn't seem to work? What should it do? What's "it"?

Answer (score -3):

Simplest way is to call

```
frame.setEnabled(false);
```

where frame is your top-level window.

Note that the above soln may change the look of frame until its enabled again. For real control people play around with EventQueue's.

Comment: -1: You need to enable the frame again when when the dialog is closed. Modal dialogs are meant for just this purpose.